# Excel to Selenium プルダウンリスト

Tags: python, excel, selenium

#### やりたいこと

Excelからデータを読み込みプルダウンリストからデータを選択したいです。
下記のコードのように試してみましたが、エラーのようにエレメントが見つかりません。

なお、45行目で以下のようにテキストを指定すると成功します。

```
select.select_by_visible_text("10時台")
```

Excelから取得したデータをサイトに選択できるようにどのようにすれば、よろしいでしょうか。

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

**エラー**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58626/devtools/browser/599625ee-cfd1-4c94-9d7b-1185b0e823a8
[11064:16504:0310/181419.128:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:14:19.129] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting Default Adapter failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/test/Documents/test/test.py", line 45, in <module>
    select.select_by_visible_text(df_a)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 140, in select_by_visible_text
    raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with visible text: %s" % text)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: 0    10時台
Name: time, dtype: object
```

**コード**

```
# coding:utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
import shutil
import pandas as pd

#headless background 
option = Options()
option.add_argument('--headless')

#Getting Default Adapter failed error message
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

#filename
filename = "test.xls"

#各項目をxlsで読み込み
df = pd.read_excel(filename,dtype=str)
df_a = df["time"]

# ブラウザを開く。 #options=option background 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

URL= "https://test.php"
# Googleの検索TOP画面を開く。
driver.get(URL)

#convenient_contact_time
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_name("time")
#セレクトタグの要素を指定してSelectクラスのインスタンスを作成

select = Select(dropdown)
#セレクトタグのオプションをテキストを指定して選択する
select.select_by_visible_text(df_a)
```

Comment: "Could not locate element with visible text: 0    10時台" と表示されていますので、`df_a` は `pandas.Series` 型のインスタンスなのでしょう。`df_a[0]` などとする必要がありそうです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。次の通りに指定しましたが同じようにエラーになります。型を変更しないといけないでしょうか
`df = pd.read_excel(filename,dtype=str,header=None,index_col=None)``df_a = df[0]
`

Comment: 失礼しました。`select.select_by_visible_text(df_o[0])`にしましたら問題なく行きました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @metropolis 
度々、すいません。追加の質問になりますが、別のプルダウンリストから上記のように指定ても下記のエラーが発生します。プルダウンリストの場合、他に何か指定する方法ありますか。
 `raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with visible text: %s" % text)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: 11:サービス`

Comment: 待機時間入れても同じエラーが表示されます。
`time.sleep(2)
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_name("business_type")
#セレクトタグの要素を指定してSelectクラスのインスタンスを作成
time.sleep(2)
select = Select(dropdown)
#セレクトタグのオプションをテキストを指定して選択する
time.sleep(2)
select.select_by_visible_text(df_w[0])`

Comment: 他の人達にも認知して貰うためにも現時点で発生している問題を質問文に追加して下さい。

Comment: @metropolis ご指摘ありがとうございます。質問追加いたしました。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: @metropolis 分かりました。エクセルで`11:サービス`のコロンが全角になっていったので、選択できませんでした。お騒がせしてすみません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの方法で解決できました。

`df_a`だとpandasのデータ型Seriesになってしまう為、 `df_a[0]` にする必要があります。
詳しくは下記のリンクを参考にしました。

pandasのインデックス参照で行・列を選択し取得[1](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-index-row-column/)

**コード:**

```
import pandas as pd

#convenient_contact_time
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_name("time")
#セレクトタグの要素を指定してSelectクラスのインスタンスを作成

select = Select(dropdown)
#セレクトタグのオプションをテキストを指定して選択する
select.select_by_visible_text(df_a[0])
```